# display images from database in horizontal way

Tags: php, css, mysql

hi this is my code which display images from mysql database

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
$id=$_POST['id'];
$q="select * from services ";
$qq=mysql_query($q)
  or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qq)){ 
  $s1=$row[image];
 ?>
                         <?php
 $p1="admin/services/uploads-services/";
 echo '<img src="'.$p1.$s1.'" class="img-responsive" alt="Blog Image">'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

it appears in vertical way but i want to make it appear in horizontal way
how can i do this ?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap and how many images you want to show in a line?

Comment: yes i have a bootstrap and i want 3 images appear in one line

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 1):

If you want images to be in same row, add `display: inline-block` to them.

```
.img-responsive {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you visualize the images not in a defined col. If you want to visualize 3 images at a line, you should have

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    put your image here
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
    put your image here
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
    put your image here
  </div>
```